# AWS Elastic Beanstalk NodeJS and logs

Tags: node.js, logging, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to migrate my NodeJS project from single EC2 to ElasticBeanstalk. In my current code I use the dependency log4js which create a log file on the filesystem. On EC2 this works create but what is the best way in ElasticBeanstalk to log something? If I download the generated logs from ElasticBeanstalk my custom log file from log4js isn't present.

Best regards

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to see the logs you can:

- Press on your elastic beanstalk environment
- Press 'Logs' (on the left side)
- Press 'Request Logs' (usually just last 100 lines should be fine) and download the file.

You can see a few different log files there.

I believe that logs you write using log4js in Node.js will be under:

> /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log

I like to ssh into the elastic beanstalk instance and tail the log to see it updating "live" (when I use my server). to do it run the following:

> eb ssh
>
> tail -n 50 -f /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log

**The above log path depends on the type of the EC2**. on Linux 2 it is: `/var/log/web.stdout.log`

In general, when you deploy to Elastic Beanstalk linux environment your app will be under:

> /var/app/current

Try finding your log files under this path- they will have the same name as when you run the app locally.

Comment: What if your EB environment has multiple load balanced EC2 instances? Wouldn't eb ssh connect to only a single EC2 instance?

Comment: Then you should ssh into your EC2s (instead of using eb ssh). Having to do it on multiple machines makes things a bit more difficult, but I don't see a way around it.

Comment: FYI on Linux 2, AWS uses `/var/log/web.stdout.log` instead of `/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`

Comment: ^^^ What @Tyler said.

Comment: Using linux 2 and I can't see /var/log/nodejs folder OR /var/log/web.stdout.log file

Comment: I also have issues on amazon linux 2. My node logs are in a `messages` file with poor formatting, and they don't show up in last 100 logs or cloudwatch log groups