# Viewing node.js logs (console.log) from docker-compose deployment on elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

New to docker and EBS. I have deployed my application to elastic beanstalk using docker-compose. Wondering how I can view the output of calling console.log() in my node.js app. Pulling the generic logs from the EBS console doesn't give me anything. I tried SSHing into the instance but poking around the filesystem, including under the  /var/log folder

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-51 log]$ ls -a
.         cfn-hup.log       cloud-init.log         docker-compose-events.log  eb-engine.log   messages  wtmp
..        cfn-init-cmd.log  cloud-init-output.log  docker-events.log          eb-publish.log  nginx     xray
amazon    cfn-init.log      cron                   eb-cfn-init-call.log       eb-tools.log    rotated
boot.log  cfn-wire.log      dmesg                  eb-cfn-init.log            healthd         sa
btmp      chrony            docker                 eb-docker                  maillog         secure
```

Apparently there should be a nodejs folder /var/log/nodejs
or /var/log/web.stdout.log ([AWS Elastic Beanstalk NodeJS and logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972267/aws-elastic-beanstalk-nodejs-and-logs))

but I cannot see either.

Answer (score 2):

To view your NodeJS `console.log` you simple use:

```
docker-compose logs <node_service_name_in_docker-compose.yml>

# add "-f" if you want to see realtime logs
```

Comment: where do i run this command? in which directory? this is presumably after i've SSHed into the EC2 instance?

Comment: You run this command on where you place your project (which has docker-compose.yml). NOT inside container